# How to upgrade Angular2 application to Angular4 application while updating through command it is upgrading it into angular 5.2.9

Tags: angular

I have updated my angular2 application by using following command for update it.

```
 npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-
 cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-
 server,router,animations}@latest typescript@latest --save
```

this command have updated my angular2 application to angular 5.2.9 which is latest version but i want to update it to most stable angular version , which is I think angular4 . so what should be change in the command.

and also my d3 dependencies not working properly after up gradation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a specific version all you have to do is target that version such as  `npm install @angular/cdk@4.0.0`. In your case

```
npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-
 cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-
 server,router,animations}@4.0.0
```

Although, I don't understand why you believe Angular v4 is more stable than Angular v5. Angular v5 is stable and by choosing to target a lower version you may end up using API's that are deprecated in later versions (in this case v5). I would recommend staying with Angular v5.

Comment: Actually we have already created an application with Angular2 but when i have integrated Ng2-tree with this application, It will throw error so for compatibility issue i have to upgrade already built application into higher version of 5 without breaking the functionality and code of previous application.